# Calculating the complementary function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question

**Find the general solution of the differential equation**
$$ y''+4y'+4y=e^{-ax} $$
**where $a$ is a constant and $a\neq2$**

I have successfully calculated the particular integral but tried using $y=\lambda e^{-ax}$ for complementary function and its particular derivatives but ended up with a quadratic equation in two variables.

What should I do?

**Edit**

[image: Working]

Comment: Could you show your working so we can check where you went wrong? You should get a quadratic equation in $a$.

Comment: The unknown is $\lambda$; that's a **linear** equation for $\lambda$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you please explain a little more?

Comment: The last line is $(a^2-4a+4)\lambda=1$. The number $a$ is known, so it's easy to write $\lambda$ in terms of $a$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ohhhhhh. I could've done that. So basically $\lambda *(a-2)^2=1$ $\lambda=\frac{1}{(a-2)^2}$